# Analysis - How does head.js implement serialization of parallel resources?

Tags: javascript, head.js

From the website -> [here](http://headjs.com)

```
// load files in parallel but execute them in sequence
head.js("file1.js", "file2.js", ... "fileN.js");
```

How is this implemented?  I'm looking in load.js -> [here](https://github.com/headjs/headjs/blob/master/src/load.js)

But can't seem to find the source where this is implemented.

Looks like `api.load` is an alias for `api.js` and is defined twice.

Answer (score 2):

If the navigator is compatible with async then it's the navigator that insures the ordering & execution of the scripts as they are just appended in the requested order (ie10, ff, chrome)

Otherwise there is a hack that is used (text/cache hack) which injects the scripts with a phony mime/type, and once they are all loaded (callback triggers) re-injects them with the correct mime/type (but since the url is already known to the browser the content is not re-fetched) thus triggering the real execution/interpretation by the browser but this time in order (ie6-ie9)